# import text file data into excel workbook VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I  have an excel workbook where the user imports text file information for calculations and plots to be generated. My code works great but I have ran into a bit of an issue. For most text files I need to start copying the information from row 2 but there is a few text files where I need to start copying information from a different row (see the two images below). So essentially I need to start copying information one row below the row that says "Depth". [image: This image has depth in the first row]

^This image has depth in the very first row of the text file.
[image]
^Whereas this image has depth further down in the text file.

Here is the code I currently have for importing the text files:

```
Sub Import_Textfiles()
Dim fName As String, LastCol As Integer

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Worksheets("Data Importation Sheet").Activate

LastCol = Cells(2, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If LastCol > 1 Then
LastCol = LastCol + 1
End If

fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub

  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fName, _
        Destination:=Cells(2, LastCol))
        .Name = "2001-02-27 14-48-00"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 2
        .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(14, 14, 8, 16, 12, 14)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

   Call Macro
   'counts the number of times this macro runs aka identifier

    Dim strShortName As String
    Dim string1 As String
    Dim reference As Range
    Dim emptycell As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim LastRow2 As Integer
    Dim LastRow3 As Integer

    i = Worksheets("Hidden").Range("B2").Value

    string1 = Worksheets("Hidden").Cells(i + 1, 1)

    Worksheets("Data Importation Sheet").Activate

    Cells(1, LastCol) = "Depth"
    Cells(1, LastCol + 1) = "A0_ " & string1
    Cells(1, LastCol + 2) = "A180_ " & string1
    Cells(1, LastCol + 3) = "A_Sum_ " & string1
    Cells(1, LastCol + 4) = "B0_ " & string1
    Cells(1, LastCol + 5) = "B180_ " & string1
    Cells(1, LastCol + 6) = "B_Sum_ " & string1


    'New Adding Reading Date to Excel Sheet:
    Dim fileDate1 As String
    Dim fileDate2 As String
    Dim A As String

    fileDate1 = Mid(fName, InStrRev(fName, "\") + 1)
    fileDate2 = Left(fileDate1, 19)

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, LastCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    LastRow2 = Cells(Rows.count, LastCol).End(xlUp).Row
    A = Cells(LastRow2, LastCol).Value

    Cells(LastRow + 1, LastCol) = "Reading Date:"
    Cells(LastRow + 2, LastCol) = fileDate2
    Cells(LastRow + 3, LastCol) = "Updating Location:"
    Cells(LastRow + 4, LastCol) = fName
    Cells(LastRow + 5, LastCol) = "Depth:"
    Cells(LastRow + 6, LastCol) = A
    Cells(LastRow + 7, LastCol) = "Identifier:"
    Cells(LastRow + 8, LastCol) = string1

    Sheets("Hidden").Activate
    LastRow3 = Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(LastRow3 + 1, 3) = fileDate2

    Call SortDates
    'organizes imported text file dates and identifiers

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me get my code to work for either case of text file data layout? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
Sub Import_Textfiles()
Dim fName As String, LastCol As Integer

Dim lngDepthRow As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Worksheets("Data Importation Sheet").Activate

LastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If LastCol > 1 Then
LastCol = LastCol + 1
End If

fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub

  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fName, _
        Destination:=Cells(2, LastCol))
        .Name = "2001-02-27 14-48-00"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 2
        .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(14, 14, 8, 16, 12, 14)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

   With ActiveSheet
        lngDepthRow = .Cells.Find(what:="Depth", lookat:=xlWhole).Row
        If lngDepthRow <> 1 Then
            .Rows("1:" & lngDepthRow).Delete shift:=xlUp
        Else
            .Rows("1").Delete shift:=xlUp
        End If
    End With

   Call Macro
   'counts the number of times this macro runs aka identifier

    Dim strShortName As String
    Dim string1 As String
    Dim reference As Range
    Dim emptycell As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim LastRow2 As Integer
    Dim LastRow3 As Integer

    i = Worksheets("Hidden").Range("B2").Value

    string1 = Worksheets("Hidden").Cells(i + 1, 1)

    Worksheets("Data Importation Sheet").Activate

    Cells(1, LastCol) = "Depth"
    Cells(1, LastCol + 1) = "A0_ " & string1
    Cells(1, LastCol + 2) = "A180_ " & string1
    Cells(1, LastCol + 3) = "A_Sum_ " & string1
    Cells(1, LastCol + 4) = "B0_ " & string1
    Cells(1, LastCol + 5) = "B180_ " & string1
    Cells(1, LastCol + 6) = "B_Sum_ " & string1


    'New Adding Reading Date to Excel Sheet:
    Dim fileDate1 As String
    Dim fileDate2 As String
    Dim A As String

    fileDate1 = Mid(fName, InStrRev(fName, "\") + 1)
    fileDate2 = Left(fileDate1, 19)

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, LastCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    LastRow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, LastCol).End(xlUp).Row
    A = Cells(LastRow2, LastCol).Value

    Cells(LastRow + 1, LastCol) = "Reading Date:"
    Cells(LastRow + 2, LastCol) = fileDate2
    Cells(LastRow + 3, LastCol) = "Updating Location:"
    Cells(LastRow + 4, LastCol) = fName
    Cells(LastRow + 5, LastCol) = "Depth:"
    Cells(LastRow + 6, LastCol) = A
    Cells(LastRow + 7, LastCol) = "Identifier:"
    Cells(LastRow + 8, LastCol) = string1

    Sheets("Hidden").Activate
    LastRow3 = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(LastRow3 + 1, 3) = fileDate2

    Call SortDates
    'organizes imported text file dates and identifiers

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Depth only occurs once in your dataset, the Split() function will probably work. Instead of using a table query, try using FileSystemsObject to import the data as a string. Then Split the data on Depth. Further Split that array by vbNewLine. Finally force TexttoColumns. Probaby not the more efficient way, but has worked for me in the past.

Basic example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DataSplit()
Dim fsoReader As Object
Dim fsoDataFile As Object
Dim strData As String
Dim strSplitAtDepth() As String
Dim strSplitAtNewLine() As String
Dim strSplitData As Variant
Dim intOffsetCounter As Integer

'opens file and reads data to a string
Set fsoReader = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fsoDataFile = fsoReader.OpenTextFile("FilePathHere", 1) '1 is ForReading
strData = fsoDataFile.ReadAll

'First split at B Sum, and wanted data guarenteed to be in second array entry.
'Second split at new line, in prep for the Text to Columns later
strSplitAtDepth() = Split(strData, "B Sum", , vbTextCompare)
strSplitAtNewLine = Split(strSplitAtDepth(1), vbLF, , vbBinaryCompare)

'Puts each newline split in its own row
intOffsetCounter = 0
For Each strSplitData In strSplitAtNewLine()
    Range("A1").Offset(0, intOffsetCounter).Value2 = strSplitData
    intOffsetCounter = intOffsetCounter + 1
Next
Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).TextToColumns ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: I get  a 'User-defined type not defined' for Dim fsoReader As Scripting.FileSystemObject

Comment: FIgured out the problem above but now on code: Range("A1").Offset(0, intOffsetCounter).Text = strSplitData   I get the error 'Object Required'

Comment: I forgot a set in front of the Range, and forgot to finish switching back to late binding. Sorry about that

Comment: Even with 'set' I still get 'Object Required' error

Comment: use value2 instead of text, and remove the Set. I tested this time (Im at work)

Comment: Okay, now I get 'input past end of file' error on the line strData = fsoDataFile.ReadAll

Comment: And when I get past that error my data all just gets placed within the first row it doesnt organize it into the columns

Comment: OpenAsTextStream("PathHere",2) should be 1(This is why I use Early binding) and the first row error means that your data is not delimeted by vbNewLine. Try vbCR, vbLF, and vbCRLF.

Comment: Tried vbCr, vbLF, and vbCRLF and none worked still just pastes the data in the first row. Also this code only works on older text files stored on my computer, when I try to open a newer one i get the 'input past end of file' error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I ended up going with, I ended up doing two if statements like so

```
Public i As Integer
Sub Import_Textfiles()
Dim fName As String, LastCol As Integer
Dim strSearch As String
Dim strSearch2 As String
Dim f As Integer
Dim lngLine As Long
Dim lngLineInt As Integer
Dim strLine As String

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Worksheets("Data Importation Sheet").Activate

LastCol = Cells(2, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If LastCol > 1 Then
LastCol = LastCol + 1
End If

fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub

strSearch = "Depth   "
strSearch2 = "Water Level"

f = FreeFile
Open fName For Input As #f
Do While Not EOF(f)
lngLine = lngLine + 1
lngLineInt = CInt(lngLine + 1)
Line Input #f, strLine
If InStr(1, strLine, strSearch, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fName, _
        Destination:=Cells(2, LastCol))
        .Name = "2001-02-27 14-48-00"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = lngLineInt
        .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(14, 14, 8, 16, 12, 14)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Exit Do
End If

If InStr(1, strLine, strSearch2, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
lngLineInt = lngLineInt + 6
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fName, _
        Destination:=Cells(2, LastCol))
        .Name = "2001-02-27 14-48-00"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = lngLineInt
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(14, 14, 8, 16, 12, 14)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Exit Do
End If
Loop
Close #f

   Call Macro
   'counts the number of times this macro runs aka identifier

    Dim strShortName As String
    Dim string1 As String
    Dim reference As Range
    Dim emptycell As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim LastRow2 As Integer
    Dim LastRow3 As Integer

    i = Worksheets("Hidden").Range("B2").Value

    string1 = Worksheets("Hidden").Cells(i + 1, 1)

    Worksheets("Data Importation Sheet").Activate

    Cells(1, LastCol) = "Depth"
    Cells(1, LastCol + 1) = "A0_ " & string1
    Cells(1, LastCol + 2) = "A180_ " & string1
    Cells(1, LastCol + 3) = "A_Sum_ " & string1
    Cells(1, LastCol + 4) = "B0_ " & string1
    Cells(1, LastCol + 5) = "B180_ " & string1
    Cells(1, LastCol + 6) = "B_Sum_ " & string1


    'New Adding Reading Date to Excel Sheet:
    Dim fileDate1 As String
    Dim fileDate2 As String
    Dim A As String

    fileDate1 = Mid(fName, InStrRev(fName, "\") + 1)
    fileDate2 = Left(fileDate1, 19)

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, LastCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    LastRow2 = Cells(Rows.count, LastCol).End(xlUp).Row
    A = Cells(LastRow2, LastCol).Value

    Cells(LastRow + 1, LastCol) = "Reading Date:"
    Cells(LastRow + 2, LastCol) = fileDate2
    Cells(LastRow + 3, LastCol) = "Updating Location:"
    Cells(LastRow + 4, LastCol) = fName
    Cells(LastRow + 5, LastCol) = "Depth:"
    Cells(LastRow + 6, LastCol) = A
    Cells(LastRow + 7, LastCol) = "Identifier:"
    Cells(LastRow + 8, LastCol) = string1


    Sheets("Hidden").Activate
    LastRow3 = Sheets("Hidden").Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(LastRow3 + 1, 3) = fileDate2

    Call SortDates

End Sub
```